# Android : Staged Roll-Out?

Tags: android

Google I/O released an option of staged roll-out for % of people, I was trying to upload an api to market but couldn't find the option for this staged roll-out, could some one help me how to achieve this.

Regards
Sreeram

Answer (score 2):

Go to "Upload a new APK", after uploading a file the bottom left of the dialog box has options like "Publish Now", "5%", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you'll only see that button if you have the UI set to simple mode.

Comment: If you are in the advanced mode you can access the Publish combobox to access staged rollout menu.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select *Upload new APK to production*
2. Browse files and upload your APK
3. Click on the down arrow beside *Publish to production*

[image]